# Conditional Probability with Powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot

my major goal is to calculate Conditional Probability over a large number of rows. Hence the use of Powerpivot.
[Attached](http://powerpivotforum.com.au/download/file.php?id=356) is an excel file with 10 rows as an example of how I did it in Excel.
My challenge is the formula in column F which I will then be needing to calculate column G.
Tamir

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the [solution](http://wimv.be/pbi/STE_solution.xlsx)

Main Formulas:
Calculate a Total, without filtering BRAND and UPS (calculated measure)

```
=CALCULATE([Total],All(Brand),All(upc))
```

Sum IF UPC (calculated column):

```
=CALCULATE([Total],filter(ALL(Fact),Fact[UPC]= EARLIER(Fact[UPC]) ))
```